# How to get inner key in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Am I able to get the inner value by key due to some function like get.
Simple dict:

```
dict1 = {
    'key1': 'asdfasdf'
}
```

If I want to get the value by `key1` I just write `dict1.get('key1')`
But what if I have such dict:

```
dict2 = {
    'some_key': {
        'key1': 'asdfasdf'
    }
}
```

How can I get value by `key1` like dict2.get('key1')?

*As you can understand I just need these both types of dictionaries, so I don't need `dict2['some_key']['key1']`*

Comment: ```print(dict2['some_key'].get('key1'))```
# asdfasdf

Answer (score 0):

That's a nested Dictionary

you can use iterated comprehension if you want to avoid using keys of top level dictionary to access inner items

e.g.

```
[x.get('key1') for x, x in dict2.items()]
```

or using just values

```
[x.get('key1') for x in x.values()]
```

this will return a list of asdfasdf

Comment: Or if you only care about the _first_ occurrence: `next(p_info.get('key1') for p_id, p_info in dict2.items())`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the value associated with the first occurrence of 'key1' in a nested dictionary, a little bit of recursion can get you there.

```
def first(d, k):
  if k in d: return d[k]
  for v in d.values():
    if isinstance(v, dict): 
      v2 = first(v, k)
      if v2: return v2
```

Consider:

```
>>> first({'a':{'b':42, 'c':27, 'd':{'e': 3.14, 'key1':'hello world'}}}, 'key1')
'hello world'
```